# Excel copy cut paste data from 1 sheet to another with a status in updated in sheet 2 new column

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to macro I have created a macro that copies data from excel sheet1 column A & B and paste it in sheet 2 with status as updates in column c. However, it is not working properly it executes with incorrect/incomplete way like for some values in sheet 2 column B it shows updated in column c but for some, it does not... Please help me below is my code.
Secondly, I have coded first for copy paste data from sheet1 to sheet2 there I have specified the range A2:A9999 and B2:B9999 I am not able to simplify it. I mean it should take the entire column A and B than the specified range. Please help me with these 2 parts.............

[image: Below is output if you see cell C2 and C3 is blank it should also populate with a remark Updated which not happening with my code]

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim i As Long
Dim wt As Excel.Worksheet

Set wr = Worksheets("Sheet2")

'Copies and cuts the data from sheet1(TIS) and paste the same in sheet2

With Worksheets("SampleFile")
    .Range("A2:A9999").Copy wr.Range("A2") 'Copy
    .Range("A2:A9999").Cut wr.Range("A2") 'Cut
    .Range("B2:B9999").Copy wr.Range("B2") 'Copy
    .Range("B2:B9999").Cut wr.Range("B2") 'Cut
End With


For i = 1 To wr.Cells(wr.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
If wr.Range("B" & i).Value = "FXV" Then
   wr.Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
   ElseIf wr.Range("B" & i).Value = "FST" Then
   wr.Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
   ElseIf wr.Range("B" & i).Value = "FLB" Then
   wr.Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
   ElseIf wr.Range("B" & i).Value = "FFH" Then
   wr.Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
   ElseIf wr.Range("B" & i).Value = "FFJ" Then
   wr.Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
   
   End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should cut data from A2 to B and `LastRow` in worksheet `SampleFile` and paste it to Range A2 in worksheet `Sheet2`. Then it will loop through all the rows in `Sheet2` looking for the value in column B, if it matches the `Select Cases` will input `Updated` in column C:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyData()

    Dim wr As Worksheet: Set wr = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    'Copies and cuts the data from sheet1(TIS) and paste the same in sheet2
    'there is no need to copy if you are going to cut
    'also use a defined range to copy instead 9999 rows
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SampleFile")
        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'you can also cut both columns at once
        .Range("A2:B" & LastRow).Cut wr.Range("A2") 'Cut
    End With
    
    Dim i As Long
    With wr
        For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        'in this case is way shorter to code using the Select statement
        'you could also use If x = y or x = z or x = a but Select looks cleaner.
            .Cells(i, "B") = Trim(.Cells(i, "B"))
            Select Case .Range("B" & i)
                Case "FXV", "FST", "FLB", "FFH", "FFJ"
                    .Range("C" & i) = "Updated"
            End Select
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for shorting the codes, however, I still encounter the same error now for FST it is not showing as updated in column c

Comment: @AkshayChari is `FST` or maybe `FST  ` with blank spaces at the end?

Comment: yes there are some space in FST,,, may be I will require one more line of code to trim and clean so that it gets updated can u please help in coding that
just I executed adding space it worked... problem is space and invalid characters in between. can we apply trim clean function in this macro